# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden (simple Web Form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, iis-8.5

I am writing a simple web form app that retrieves data from xml. It seems like I tried everything that was recommended as shown in the picture but error still exists. Used IIS Express to solve the problem but it just doesn't work. Please help.

[image]

Comment: What URL are you trying to navigate?

Comment: Doing it locally :Localhost

Comment: You haven't set any default startup page. Try setting one because IIS doesn't know what to do when you run your website as `http://localhost:8080/` for example. More over you can also set a default page from web.config.

Comment: Should I do it in ISS Manager? Could you provide brief tutorial? @SuprabhatBiswal

Comment: Here, you go [Setting default page in Asp.Net webform](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-default-page-for-your-website-in-IIS-using-WebConfig-file-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: You are my hero Mr.@SuprabhatBiswal Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Actually it is possible that you just need to set a default page for your application. 
You can right-click at a page in your application then select `Set As Start Page`

**First Answer**

Try to run in `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`

command:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

with administrator rights.

Comment: I am thinking default page setup might be the problem too. Could you tell me where I should set a Start Page?

Comment: Do you have any `html` or `aspx` or any web file in your project? I suppose yes. Right click on it in solution explorer and chose `Set As Start Page` (As I mentioned in my asnwer)