# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

i'm new with asp.net
i'm using web forms ,so when i add a new web form master page this error occurs
[image: link]

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: http://localhost:56523/

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like http://localhost:56523/page.aspx?

Comment: As per the error, if you arent going to a specific page then you need a default doc setup in iis (express).

Comment: yeah it is  localhost:56523/WebForm1.aspx ,sry

Comment: You need to make sure that proper authentication modules are installed and enabled as part of IIS on your windows machine. For your case it looks like Anonymous and Digest Authentication should be installed and enabled.

Comment: Check permission on the filesystem too but as Chetan says, your authentication prob doesnt have Anonymous set to true also.

Comment: as i said i'm not familiar with this stuff, can you plz tell me how to fix it or provide some links

Comment: Try this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730758/

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting `set as start page` by right clicking on the file in solution explorer and then run